Как получить окно, которому принадлежит UserControl на avalonia?
Я пытаюсь открыть диалоговое окно из кастомного UserControl, для его открытия необходимо текущее окно. Как я могу получить окно для UserControl?
Код во View UserControl, в котором я пытаюсь получить окно, которому принадлежит этот UserControl. Но мне не очень нравится этот вариант.
  private async Task ShowDialogAsync(InteractionContext<FilterGhartsViewModel,
                                  bool> interaction)
  {
      var dialog = new FilterGharts
      {
          DataContext = interaction.Input
      };
      var window = this.GetVisualRoot();
      var result = await dialog.ShowDialog<bool>((Window)window);
  } 


Уточните, пожалуйста, получить где? Во View, во ViewModel или ещё где-то? Желательно с примером кода.

Во  View у UserControl
